# JFreeChart's plot doesn't intersect with the axes

Tags: java, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I'm currently using JFreeChart, but the the end of my plot doesn't intersect with the axes, plz have a look at my pic.

How could I get rid of that problem?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the margins on your domain axis to zero:

```
ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setLowerMargin(0);
axis.setUpperMargin(0);
```